# How to call multiple databases in Microsoft Powershell

Tags: sql, database, powershell

I have command that removes admin rights for users in a database. Then I run another script that adds admin rights afterwards.

The script to remove admin rights is:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Database "MailboxDatabase4" | Remove-MailboxPermission -user "admin" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

The script to add admin rights is:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Database "MailboxDatabase4" | Add-MailboxPermission -user "admin" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

I Have 6 databases, therefore I have to run the scripts 12 times each day. Is there any way of calling all the databases in one script so that I only have to run one script for all the databases to remove admin rights, then another script to add admin rights. Therefore not having to do it for each individual database.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `-Database` parameter in your call?

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ...
```

`Get-Mailbox` will then return all mailboxes at once. This could be a costly venture depending on the size of the organization.

You could also collect all databases then call `Get-Mailbox` in a loop but that would be no different then what is happening above.

```
$dbs = get-mailboxdatabase | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$dbs | ForEach-Object{
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Database $_ | ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your answer. In Regards to it being a "costly venture" could you please elaborate. I have roughly 1200 mailboxes spread across 6 databases. do you think it would be okay to remove the -database. And will that call all 6 databases at once.

Comment: @user3481230 You would just have to test. 1200 should not be to bad. Understand that it can take more than a minute to enumerate all those mailboxes. It's when you get into the thousands (plural) that you can run into performance and memory issues.